# jquery div is not updating when edited

Tags: jquery

Here is my code which creates dynamic divs and when i enter the strength of the room it will display the starting and ending numbers of seating in the respective divs. But when i change the strength of the rooms previously entered the starting and ending numbers are not changing in the div's

First program is for form

```
 <html>
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
   $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({

           dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'

        });
   });

   </script>
 <style>

  input
  {
    height:30px;  
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="test1.php" target="_blank">   
       <center><table border="0">

      <tr>
       <td class="td-font">Select the Year:</td>

       <td class="td-details"> 
        <select name="yr" id="yr" class="select-type" required>
        <option value="" selected>---Select---</option>
        <option value="1">1  </option>
        <option value="2">2  </option>
        <option value="3">3  </option>
        <option value="4">4  </option>
        </select>
       </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="td-font">Select the Sem:</td>

        <td class="td-details"> 
            <select name="sm" id="sm" class="select-type" required>
                <option value="" selected>---Select---</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="td-font">Select the Course:</td>

        <td class="td-details"> 
            <select name="crs" class="select-type" required>
                <option value="" selected>---Select---</option>
                <option value="1A">B.Tech</option>
                <option value="1R">B.Pharma</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td class="td-font">Select the reg:</td>

        <td class="td-details"> 
            <select name="reg" class="select-type" required>
                <option value="" selected>---Select---</option>
                <option value="R07">R07 Reg</option>
                <option value="R10">R10 Reg</option>
                <option value="R13">R13 Reg</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>       


     <tr>
         <td class="td-font">Select Date:</td>
         <td class="td-details">
               <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="dt" required>            
         </td>
    </tr> 


    <tr>
        <td class="td-font">Select the Session:</td>

        <td class="td-details"> 
            <select name="ss" class="select-type" required>
                <option value="" selected>---Select---</option>
                <option value="FN">FN </option>
                <option value="AN">AN</option>
            </select>
         </td>
    </tr> 


    <tr>
        <td colspan=2><center><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn-success"></center></td>
    <tr>

   </table></center>
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

second program starts here

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css" />

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var x=2;
          var rem=0;   


          $('#add').click(function(){
          var maxfields=50;

            if(x<=maxfields)
             {    
  $('#more').append('<br><div id="p1">Room '+x+': <input type="text" name="room[]" maxlength="10"> Strength '+x+': <input type="text" name="stre[]" class="room" min="1" max="36"><div id="div'+x+'">'+x+'</div></div></br>');
            x++;
        }
else
{
  alert('you reached the max limit');
}

      });

    });
   </script>
 <style>
   input
   {
     height:30px;  
   }
   #add
   {
      background-color:#ffffff;
      font-family:arial;
      border-radius:5px;
      border-collapse:collapse;
      border:1px solid #d6d6d6;
      height:30px; 
   }
  td
  {
     height:30px;
     width:125px;
     text-align:center;
     font-weight:bold;
  }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <?php
     include('connect.php');
     $year=$_POST['yr'];
     $sem=$_POST['sm'];
     $date=$_POST['dt'];
     $course=$_POST['crs'];
     $session=$_POST['ss'];
     $reg=$_POST['reg'];

     session_start();
     $_SESSION['yr']=$year;
     $_SESSION['sm']=$sem;
     $_SESSION['dt']=$date;
     $_SESSION['crs']=$course;
     $_SESSION['ss']=$session;
     $_SESSION['rg']=$reg;


      $sql="select * from seating where year='$year' and sem='$sem' and course='$course' and session='$session' and reg='$reg' and date='$date'";
      $query=mysql_query($sql);
      $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
    ?>

    <center><table border='1'>
      <tr><td>Total Strength</td><td>Remaining</td></tr>
      <tr><td><?php echo"$count";?></td><td><div id="rem"></div></td>       </tr>
     </table></center>


     <br></br>
     <div class='disp'>
      <button id="add">Add Room</button><br></br>
       <form method="post" action="rooms_post.php" target="_parent">
       <div id="p1">Room 1: <input type="text" name="room[]" maxlength="10"> Strength 1: <input type="text" name="stre[]" class="room" min="1" max="36"><div id="div1">This is div1</div></div><br>
       <div id="more"></div></div><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn-success" disabled="disabled" />
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        var rem=0;
        var tot=<?php echo $count; ?>;
        $("#rem").html(tot).val();

      $(document).on("change",".room",function(){

var sum = 0;
var k=0;

$(".room").each(function(){

    k=k+1;      
    sum += +$(this).val();
    var cap=$(this).val();
    var start=sum-cap+1;
    var end=sum;
    alert(start);
    alert(end);
    $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'disp.php',
            data:'start_id='+start+'&end_id='+end,
            success:function(gethtml)
            {
                $("#div"+k).html(gethtml);                  
            }
        });         
});

      if(sum%4==0)
     {

        rem=tot-sum;

       $("#rem").html(rem).val()

       if(rem==0)
       {
          $("#add").attr("disabled", true);
          $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", false);    
          $("#rem").css("background-color", "#ffa5a5");  
       }
      else if(rem<0)
       {
         alert('Capacity exceeded the remaining');
         $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", true);  
         $("#add").attr("disabled", true);  
       }
       else
       {
         $("#add").attr("disabled", false);  
         $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", true);
         $("#rem").css("background-color", "#a9fc97");   
       }
     }
   else
  {

 alert('Capacity must be multiple of 4');
 $(".btn-success").attr("disabled", true);  
 $("#add").attr("disabled", true);  
  }  
});

  </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

here is another program disp.php

```
    <html>
      <head>

      </head>

     <?php

        include('connect.php');

        $start=$_POST['start_id'];
        $end=$_POST['end_id'];
        echo"from $start to $end";

     ?>
     </html>
```